# How to add List<> to a List<> in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Is there a short way to add List<> to List<> instead of looping in result and add new result one by one?

```
var list = GetViolations(VehicleID);
var list2 = GetViolations(VehicleID2);

list.Add(list2);
```

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Use [List.AddRange(collection As IEnumerable(Of T))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method.

It allows you to append at the end of your list another collection/list.

Example:

```
List<string> initialList = new List<string>();
// Put whatever you want in the initial list
List<string> listToAdd = new List<string>();
// Put whatever you want in the second list
initialList.AddRange(listToAdd);
```

Answer (score 17):

Try using `list.AddRange(VTSWeb.GetDailyWorktimeViolations(VehicleID2));`

Comment: also get rid of the 
 List<VTSWeb.WorktimeViolation> list = new List<VTSWeb.WorktimeViolation>();
statement as it's redundant.

Comment: @WOPR: Is there a better method to do this? Gimme an example use..

Answer (score 17):

1. Use `Concat` or `Union` extension methods. You have to make sure that you have this declaration `using System.Linq;` in order to use LINQ extensions methods.
2. Use the `AddRange` method.

Comment: Exactly. Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` direction.

Answer (score 9):

Use `.AddRange` to append any Enumrable collection to the list.